# Меняется ли роль?

Tags: субстантивация

При субстантивации меняется роль в предложении?

> Лучший [продавец] станет директором!

В таком случае предложение будет характеризоваться как неполное двусоставное или полное двусоставное (если не будет сущ. в предложении)?

Comment: Не совсем понятно: *Лучший [продавец] станет продавцом!* Продавец станет продавцом? Если это о конкурсе или профотборе, то, наверно, лучше сказать *конкурсант* или *участник*.

Comment: Слово в скобочках только смысл передает. Само предложение не содержит этого слова, так как оно будет квалифицироваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полное двусоставное.

РГ-80 называет такие ситуации замещением компонента простого предложения. Ну а раз есть элемент, замещающий подлежащее, уже не сказать, что неполное.

Об этом [РГ-80 РЕГУЛЯРНЫЕ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ ПРОСТОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1952-1959.html), § 1957, пункт 2) Замещение подлежащего неизменяемым прилагательным типа помоложе или формой косвенного падежа: *Помоложе работают лучше, чем пожилые; Дамы почти все уже сидели... Посмелее из них обмахивались платочками (Дост.); Из прохожих стали засматриваться. Иные даже приостанавливались (Дост.)*

Comment: А если, например, замещается не подлежащее? Рассказ относится к послевоенным годам: или сороковому, или пятидесятому [году]. Тут тот же самый принцип?

Comment: Нет. РГ-80 говорит о грамматической основе. Ваш пример - стандартное соблюдение благозвучия (зачем повторять слово «году», если вот оно рядом стоит обобщающим).

Comment: Это понятно, но ведь оно подразумевается.